# Get tablespace and percentage values as a normal user

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I created a user like this:

```
create user demouser identified by admin; 
GRANT DBA to demouser;
```

My problem is I want to get tablespaces and used percentage by using this user.

I created a procedure to get this information, but I can oly run it as sys as sysdba:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE E_Types as
PROCEDURE TestProc (p_recordset OUT SYS_REFCURSOR); END E_Types; 
/ CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY E_Types IS
PROCEDURE TestProc (p_recordset OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS 
BEGIN 
  OPEN p_recordset 
  FOR 
     select a.TABLESPACE_NAME as Tablespace,round((1-((a.BYTES-nvl(b.BYTES,0))/a.BYTES))*100,2) AS Percentages 
     from 
     (
        select TABLESPACE_NAME, sum(BYTES) BYTES 
        from sys.dba_data_files 
        group by TABLESPACE_NAME
     ) a, 
     (
        select TABLESPACE_NAME, sum(BYTES) BYTES 
        from sys.dba_free_space 
        group by TABLESPACE_NAME
     ) b 
     where a.TABLESPACE_NAME = b.TABLESPACE_NAME (+) 
     order by ((a.BYTES-b.BYTES)/a.BYTES) desc; 
 END; 
END; /
```

I want to connect from NetBeans using "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","DEMOUSER","admin" rather than "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","sys as sysdba","admin".

Comment: Firstly, don't create objects in the `SYS` schema. It's very rarely necessary or wise. What happens when you call the procedure as your normal user? Do you get an error?

Comment: `GRANT EXECUTE ON sys.TestProc TO demouser;` to begin with

Comment: @Alex poole - sir,   i tried to call with demouser URL but error BUT RESULT IS WORK CORRECTLY WITH SYS AS SYSDBA.

Comment: @sebas- sir i tried  Grant succeeded. but did not not work.sir sorry i wrote procedure inside the package called E_Type.like this 

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE E_Types as PROCEDURE TestProc (p_recordset OUT SYS_REFCURSOR); END E_Types; rest of code can't put charactor because of limitation. help me please

Comment: Edit the question to put new information in, especially code; don't try to add it as a comment. Also please show the actual error you got; just saying 'error' isn't helpful. And exactly how you're calling it.

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY E_Types IS 
     
    PROCEDURE TestProc (p_recordset OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS
    BEGIN
    OPEN p_recordset FOR
    select a.TABLESPACE_NAME as
    Tablespace,round((1-((a.BYTES-nvl(b.BYTES,0))/a.BYTES))*100,2) AS
    Percentages from (select TABLESPACE_NAME, sum(BYTES) BYTES from
    sys.dba_data_files group by TABLESPACE_NAME) a, (select
    TABLESPACE_NAME, sum(BYTES) BYTES from sys.dba_free_space group by
   TABLESPACE_NAME) b where a.TABLESPACE_NAME = b.TABLESPACE_NAME (+)
   order by ((a.BYTES-b.BYTES)/a.BYTES) desc;
   END;
   END;
   /

Comment: NETBEANS ERROR IS " SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 15:
PLS-00905: object E_TYPES.TESTPROC is invalid
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored"

Comment: Please **edit the question to put new information in**, especially code; don't try to add it as a comment. It's not the connection, the package isn't valid; are you creating the package as `demouser` now? If so it looks like an authid issue; the only grants are from roles, which are not active in a names PL/SQL block.

Comment: Never, ever under no circumstance use the `SYS` (or `SYSTEM`) account for your development work. Stop using it.

Comment: i got the answer thanx for all for help me advice me.i'm new to oracle and i am trying to measure database performance.

i have grant
 GRANT SELECT ON dba_free_space TO demouser;
GRANT SELECT ON dba_data_files TO demouser;